# React - Dynamically update the total on new input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three input fields of type number (controlled input to accept numbers in range [0-100]). And one text field to display the total.

**Input Fields:**

```
<Input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={this.updateCode1} />
<Input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={this.updateCode2} />
<Input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={this.updateCode3} />
```

**Total Field:**

```
<Text fontSize={14} weight={700}>{this.state.total}</Text>
```

**UpdateCodes functions:**

```
updateCode1(value) {
    this.setState({ code1: value },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }
updateCode2(value) {
     this.setState({ code2: value },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }
updateCode3(value) {
     this.setState({ code3: value },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }
```

**UpdateTotal:**

```
updateTotal() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      total: (prevState.code1 + prevState.code2 + prevState.code3),
    }),
    () => {
      if (this.state.total !== 100) {
        this.setState({ isTotalInvalid: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ isTotalInvalid: false });
      }
    });
  }
```

**But it is not calculating the total. Any ideas? Thanks!**

Comment: Is it throwing an error? How do you know it's not calculating the totals?

Comment: Where does `Input` come from? A normal `input` will not pass the `value` directly to the handler like that, it will pass an event. Unless your implementation of `Input` is different, that may be your problem.

Comment: Have you bind all the functions in constrctor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` passed to `updateCodeX` is not the value it self but the `event` the value is inside `event.target.value`, and add `+` to cast the state values to numbers :

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    code1: 40,
    code2: 40,
    code3: 40,
    total : 0
  }
  
  updateCode1 = e => {
    this.setState({
        code1: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }
  updateCode2 = e => {
    this.setState({
        code2: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }
  updateCode3 = e => {
    this.setState({
        code3: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }

  updateTotal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        total: (+prevState.code1 + +prevState.code2 + +prevState.code3),
      }),
      () => {
        if (this.state.total !== 100) {
          this.setState({
            isTotalInvalid: true
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            isTotalInvalid: false
          });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={this.updateCode1} />
          <input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={this.updateCode2} />
          <input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={this.updateCode3} />
          Total Field:

          <span fontSize={14} weight={700}>{this.state.total}</span>
        </div>);
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render( < Test / > , document.querySelector('#test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

I would suggest a slight improvement on your code, use one function `updateCode` to update the codes in state :

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    code1: 40,
    code2: 40,
    code3: 40,
    total : 0
  }
  
  updateCode = (e, k) => {
    this.setState({
        [`code${k}`]: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
        this.updateTotal();
      });
  }

  updateTotal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        total: (+prevState.code1 + +prevState.code2 + +prevState.code3),
      }),
      () => {
        if (this.state.total !== 100) {
          this.setState({
            isTotalInvalid: true
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            isTotalInvalid: false
          });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={e => this.updateCode(e, 1)} />
          <input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={e => this.updateCode(e, 2)} />
          <input type="number" defaultValue="40" min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onBlur={e => this.updateCode(e, 3)} />
          Total Field:

          <span fontSize={14} weight={700}>{this.state.total}</span>
        </div>);
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render( < Test / > , document.querySelector('#test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one shot with one handler as below:
a working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2k3iviKRIGejapy6?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview)

```
  handleInput = (e) => {
    const key = e.target.name;
    if (!key) { return; }

    const value = e.target.value ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : 0;
    const oldValue = this.state[key] ? this.state[key] : 0;
    const total = (this.state.total - this.state[key]) + value;
    console.log('key: ', key, ' value: ', value, ' total: ', total);

    this.setState({ [key]: value, total })
  }
```